# using selenium for getting page source, how to use my code on server which doesnot have firefox?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium

When I use selenium for getting the page source, it will use the selenium server through the system Firefox. How can I load my code on the server when it doesn't have Firefox?

```
Web-driver driver = new Firefox-driver();
        driver.navigate().to(url);
        String st = driver.getPageSource();
        driver.close();
```

Comment: What do you intend to do? Why for heaven's sake would you execute a selenium test on the server? You can just run the test locally on your machine but use the production(deployment) url.

Comment: I just want to get page source. not doing any test.

Comment: It does not matter if you would get the source only or run a test. There is no point in running selenium web driver on the deployment server. Perhaps you should elaborate more on why would you need the pages' source for - is that part of your application's logic?

Comment: Yes, part of my application.

Comment: Since not able to get particular data from page source using httpclient and jsoup i am using selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Headless firefox is an option if selenium used for scraping/crawling only
follow the link http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 1):

I got answer for my question...
we can install firefox on server and and provide browser a virtual display by installing
X-Virtual FrameBuffer - A Headless Firefox
Install Firefox headless in Ubuntu, follow commands
ppa:mozillateam/firefox-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firefox
Install Xvfb – the X Virtual FrameBuffer
sudo apt-get install xvfb
following links give in detail
http://www.installationpage.com/selenium/how-to-run-selenium-headless-firefox-in-ubuntu/

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlUnitDriver, instead of FirefoxDriver.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.navigate().to(url);
String st = driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(st);
driver.close();
```

Comment: not getting the data what is required for me using HtmlUnit as well.